# Delphi - Resume file upload using TMagFtp component

Tags: delphi, ftp

I am using TMagFtp component that in turn is built using OveByte's ICS component sets as its base, for uploading files to FTP server.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
Replace := FCReplDiff;

taskres := MagFTPClient.FtpLogon;
if taskres = TaskResOKNew then
begin
    for I := 1 to lstFiles.Count - 1 do
    begin
        UploadFileName := lstFiles.Items[I];
        UploadFileName := ExtractFileName(UploadFileName);
        taskres := MagFTPClient.FtpUpOneFile(ProjectFolderPath + UploadFileName, '/jobs/' + ProjectFolderName, ExtractFileName(UploadFileName), Replace);
        if (taskres = TaskResFail) then
        begin
            ShowMessage('Upload Failed' + #13 + GetTaskResName(taskres) + #13 + GetExceptMess(ExceptObject));
            UploadFailed := True;
            Exit;
        end;
    end;

end;
```

Once a file is uploaded and I repeat the upload process it re-uploads the file. Where in fact it should skip the file. The FTP server in question supports Resume. I checked that with Filezilla.

I don't understand as to why?

Comment: What exactly does FCReplDiff mean?

Comment: It is a parameter that tells MagFTP to only upload files that are different in size then the target file

Comment: Another I observed that Uploading keeps failing on Windows 8.Why?

Comment: I added some debugging directions to my answer and I believe I have answered your question. Regarding failure on Windows 8 would be another question as it is unrelated to this one.

Answer (score 1):

The `Replopt` parameter of

```
TMagFtp.FtpUpOneFile(const LocFileFull, RemTarDir, RemTarFile: string; Replopt: TFileCopyRepl): TTaskResult;
```

takes on of the following values:

```
TFileCopyRepl = (FCReplNever, FCReplAlways, FCReplDiff, FCReplNewer) ;
```

Using `FCReplNever` presumably never replaces existing files.

---

Edit.

Looking at the source, it seems `FCReplDiff` means that the file can be replaced if it is of different size or its timestamp differs more than `AllowDiffDT` which has a default value of 2 seconds. It may be that the FTP server is running under a different timezone and especially at these times when DST changes happen at different times in different countries, the time of file at the server is reported to have a different time, even if it was uploaded the first time just before.

---

Edit 2

The above theory on differences in times can not be assessed by the info in your question. Therefore, to verify, put a breakpoint on line 4507

```
    flag := MagCheckReplace (replopt, true, OneSecond * 2, SrcFSize, RFSize,
                                                           SrcFileUDT, RFileUDT) ;
```

in MagentaFtp.pas and check the values of `SrcFileUDT` and `RFileUDT`. Also step into the `MagCheckReplace()` function to see why it allows a replacement.